# ThreeJS sound keeps playing after moving to other page with React Link & UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, three.js, use-effect

I'm currently working on a project with ThreeJS and sound. I have a scene with different kind of object that have audio. All these objects are coming from a Firebase database. I use Mobx as statemanager. There is a button on the page to go to a different page. The problem I have is that when I go to this new page, the audio from the last page keeps playing. And when I come back to the first page, the audio is doubled.

This is the code I use:

```
React.useEffect(
  () =>
    autorun(() => {
      const createPins = () => {
        pinStore.pins.map((pin) => {
          let geo = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(1, 0);
          let mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 16643437,
            shininess: 10,
            flatShading: true,
          });

          const pointer = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
          scene.add(pointer);

          const audio = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);
          audioLoader.load("../../assets/audio/techno.mp3", (buffer) => {
            audio.setBuffer(buffer);
            audio.setLoop(true);
            audio.setRefDistance(3);
            audio.play();
          });
          pointer.add(audio);
        });
      };
    }),
  []
);

return (
  <>
    <Link to="/create">CREATE</Link>
  </>
);
```

Is there a way that when I go to a new page, the audio from the objects stop playing and when I come back to the page I hear the audio again.

Answer (score 0):

Return a function from within the function in `useEffect` and stop the audio in that function. This will stop the audio anytime that component is unmounted.

```
React.useEffect(
  () => {
    autorun(() => {
      const createPins = () => {
        pinStore.pins.map((pin) => {
          let geo = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(1, 0);
          let mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 16643437,
            shininess: 10,
            flatShading: true,
          });

          const pointer = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
          scene.add(pointer);

          const audio = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);
          audioLoader.load("../../assets/audio/techno.mp3", (buffer) => {
            audio.setBuffer(buffer);
            audio.setLoop(true);
            audio.setRefDistance(3);
            audio.play();
          });
          pointer.add(audio);
        });
      };
    });

    return () => {
      // stop audio here...
    };
   },
  []
);

return (
  <>
    <Link to="/create">CREATE</Link>
  </>
);
```